# Error en PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en PHP, estoy haciendo unos tests de prueba, el caso es que ejecuto el comando `phpunit --vebose EjemploTest.php`

Y me da el siguiente error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\Util\ErrorHandler::invokeIgnoringWarnings() in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/DefaultTestResultCache.php:150
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php(180): PHPUnit\Runner\DefaultTestResultCache->load()
#1 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(200): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->doRun()
#2 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(159): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run()
#3 /usr/bin/phpunit(42): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/DefaultTestResultCache.php on line 150
```

Comment: ¿Que versión de PHP y PHPUnit estas usando?

Comment: @Marcos de php, 7.4.3 y de PHPUnit, 8.5.2